# entity framework update foreign key throws exception if AutoDetectChangesEnabled set false

Tags: entity-framework

I have table A and B
A like : id
         name
         bid
B like : id
         type

in table A has a data record reference with B1,now I want update A reference with B2.
in my unitofwork if I set AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true it's work ok, but I set AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false reason is I want to up speed throw the exception like this:
The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'GoodsKind.goods_kind_id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'EnrolmentType.goods_kind' on the other end."

how cand i do?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error as well. The problem for me was that I have a complex type. When I changed the master record (let's say Person) I also wanted to change the complex type List with his contact information(s). So when I tried to save them both in one screen I got this error. Check if you fill all the ids on your screen for the master record and the complex type records. Check if they are posted to the server (if you use in example MVC). You can do this by checking the `Bind` statement by your MVC action.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the ID and the object specified doesn't match. This means that you are saying that A has a B with ID=2 but at the same time you have A with an object of type B with ID=5. Because you are working in a disconnected environment, EF doesn't know which one is the correct. To solve this issue you can do one of the following things:
-Get the object from EF, modify it and then save (connected environment).
OR
-Update the IDs manually (update A setting ID=5 because the object B has ID=5).

Always remember that EF tracks changes if it is in a connected environment and the tracking is enabled. If not, it has no clue of the changes you made until it tries to save it in the DB (where the object is compared with the values in the DB). One thing that you can do to manually tell EF that the entity has been modified in a disconnected environment is:

```
dbContext.Entry(objectA).State = EntityState.Modified;
```